# Fallback for people without Javascript is flashed before jQuery is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I basically have something like this:

```
<div id="slide-1" style="display:none;">
  Not too important stuff
</div>
<div id="slide-2">
  Important stuff
</div>
<script>
$('#slide-2').hide(0,function(){
  $('#slide-1').fadeIn();
});
</script>
```

However, "slide-2" is showing up for about half a second before the jQuery is executed, and the files are all on my computer. If someone else views it, the delay would be long. How can I prevent the user from seeing "slide-2"?

Comment: When are you executing your javascript, in document.ready() or onload or inline?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){}); It loads after everything else has loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use jQuery for hiding that little div.  The delay may be due to the browser waiting for jQuery to download.  Use simple javascript right after it like so:

```
<div id="slide-1" style="display:none;">
  Not too important stuff
</div>
<div id="slide-2">
  Important stuff
</div>
<script>
  document.getElementById('slide-2').style.display = 'none'
</script>
```

Comment: Pickle brings up a good point. By using inline js the page will halt rendering while it is executed. This will most definitely solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `noscript` tag to show content to individuals without javascript. So something like this should work.

```
<noscript>
  <div id="slide-2">
    Important stuff
  </div>
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

Slide-2 could be hidden with `display:none;`

Without knowing exactly how the slides work, it's difficult to say how appropriate the solution is.

Comment: His problem is that he wants slide-2 shown for people that don't have javascript. So `display: none` hides it for them also.

Comment: Ah yes, important details in the title. In that case the noscript tag is probably the best solution.